# Change in pH when changing the sequence of acidic solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, ph

I have 4 acidic solutions: Barium nitrate, aluminium nitrate monohydrate, cobalt nitrate hexahydrate, and hexachloroplatinic acid. Everything is dissolved in water.

I mixed them in order to create a final acidic solution. Following is the mixing procedure

1)Platinic acid =>Cobalt Nitrate=>Alumnium Nitrate=>Barium Nitrate
(This means Aluminium Nitrate was added to Barium Nitrate , to the mixture of which cobalt nitrate was added, and finally, chloroplatinic acid was added.)

Now, when I add everything to barium nitrate, the final $\mathrm{pH}$ of the mixture is always around 1.5,

2)Barium Nitrate =>Aluminium Nitrate =>Cobalt Nitrate =>Platinic acid

When I add everything to chloroplatinic acid, the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the mixture drops to around 0.3-0.5. Also if I do some other sequence, the $\mathrm{pH}$ is different.

The following are the details of the solutions-

Barium Nitrate- 2.1 g in 40 ml of water (0.008 moles) (0.2 M)

Aluminium Nitrate Nonahydrate-33.1 g in 40 ml of water (0.088 moles) (2.2 M)

Cobalt Nitrate-1.86 g in 40 ml of water (0.0064 moles) (0.16 M)

Hexachloroplatinic acid-0.83 g in 40 ml of water (0.0016 moles) (0.04 M)

I am trying to understand why this is happening because ultimately every time the constituents are the same, but why is the sequence of the addition causing this change?

Since always conceptualizing $\mathrm{pH}$ in terms of $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$, I am having a hard time trying to understand how the nitrates and the chloroplatinic acid are behaving with each other and with the water molecules and how exactly the final $\mathrm{pH}$ is dependent on them.

The $\mathrm{pH}$ of individual solutions when I measured them in our lab are:

- barium nitrate: 6.2;
- aluminium nitrate: 1.71;
- cobalt nitrate: 5.46; and
- hexachloroplatinic acid: less than 1.

Looking at these numbers, I can see why adding everything to hexachloroplatinic acid is giving less $\mathrm{pH}$ than adding everything to barium nitrate, but what mechanism is playing part here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Know what the concentration of each solution is? Was anything added to any of the solutions to stabilize it?

Comment: It would be interesting to know exactly what you have done. For example, what are the concentrations of your four solutions, and what are the volumes of your solutions  used for preparing your mixture ? Do you use the same volumes for all your different mixtures ? Do you use one drop of the first reagent and 1 liter of the second ? And also why do you carry out this strange mixture ? What for ? Hexachloroplatinic acid is an expensive reagent...

Comment: yeah sorry should have mentioned the concentrations-

Comment: @MaxW I dont add anything to stabilize them

Comment: @Maurice I use it to synthesis metal oxides .Yes ,I am aware of the cost of Hexachloroplatinic acid

Comment: Did you boil the distilled(?) water to get rid of $\ce{CO2}$ before making the solutions. Did you measure the pH of that water?

Comment: As @Maurice asked, please explain your mixing experiment in detail. Which solutions, the order, and volume of each.

Comment: @MaxW  I have edited the question, please take a look

Comment: @user86428 - what volumes of each solution?

Comment: @user86428 - all in all there is obviously some sort of concentration dependent reaction happening. I'd suspect that the reaction is between the solutions of aluminum nitrate and hexachloroplatinic acid.